# Assertion error while reading csv with delimter ¶

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a source file, in which delimiter is defined as '¶'

Sample source file:

```
Cust_name¶Age¶ID
John¶32¶123
Max¶20¶212
```

I am creating a data frame in AWS glue script(executing in spark) for the above file using simple command of data frames:

```
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=inbound_bucket, Key=file_name)
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'],skiprows=1, sep='¶',header=None, encoding='utf-8',engine='python')
```

With above code, I am getting assertion error, I have tried many things to define the "sep" property but none are working. Can someone please help!!!

Comment: Try using `sep='\n'`

Comment: What exact assertion error are you getting?